# App engine --ignore-file not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Depending on the env I deploy to I want to ignore diffrent files but using `--ignore-file` option does not work.

I have tried:

```
gcloud app deploy app.prod.yaml --ignore-file=.gcloudignore.prod --project project-id
gcloud app deploy app.prod.yaml --ignore-file .gcloudignore.prod --project project-id
gcloud app deploy app.prod.yaml --ignore-file=.gcloudignore.prod --project project-id --no-cache
```

None of them worked.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this same situation on my side. I have found an [Issue Tracker thread for this same issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/135667495). Currently it seems as it always uses the .gcloudignore file no matter the --ignore-file flag.